# Adjust space between chevron and slide using slickR

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, slickr

I am using Rmarkdown and slickR to create a carousel of images. How do I adjust the space between the left chevron and the left edge of the slide?

[image]

````
---
  title: Carousel test
---
  
  Here is a carousel

```{r, label='HIS-table', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
library("htmlwidgets")
library("slickR")
library("tidyverse")

num_slides <- 3


filenames <- c(
  "http://placehold.it/600x300/565656/ffffff&text=Slide+1",
  "http://placehold.it/600x300/565656/ffffff&text=Slide+2",
  "http://placehold.it/600x300/565656/ffffff&text=Slide+3"
)

slickR(obj = filenames, height = 300, width = "95%") +
  settings(dots = TRUE)
```
There was a carousel
````

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the width to 70%, the margin becomes smaller and so on. I also saw some auto margin settings here, https://yonicd.github.io/slickR/articles/doms.html. Might be able to explicitly set the margins that way.